# wrapfigure doesn't work if there is a { in the beginning of a paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure, scoping

I would like to have `\addfontfeature` scoped around one word in the beginning of a paragraph. However, it turns out it breaks `wrapfigure`, which does all kinds of weird stuff in this case. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick, red] (0,0) circle [radius = 1.5cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

The figure goes outside of the paper. I tried hiding `{Lorem}` inside a macro defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, but with no success.

[image]